# mySQL load data local infile incorrect number import operation

Tags: mysql, csv

I m trying to import data from a csv file to a database mysql that contains a column with type `float`. 
So when i used the command  :

```
load DATA INFILE 'd:/dropbox/Dropbox/applications/glimp/f.csv' 
INTO TABLE iot_dataa 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(duration,date,fields1,fields2,fields3,fields4,rate,fields5,fields6,deviceid);
```

I got  the field with type float number with values of '0' in all lines.

CSV file

[image: CSV file]

Table definition
[image: schema]

mysql table
[image: mysql table]

Comment: Please add your table definition and a few lines from your CSV file as text

Comment: I updated my publication so you can review it please

Comment: Here's a thing, if you add as TEXT we can copy it, work on it.